# how to log which page was "not found"? (Trying custom error page with htaccess, php, http_referer)

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-referer

I was just wondering how to get 
the link of the webpage which was not found on my website.

With following .htaccess code, when a non-existing page is requested, user is redirected to my_404.php.

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.com/my_404.php
```

If I have to track down what was the link of the page, which was not found, how do I do that??

Just for example, A.php is a valid web page, while b.php is not. So if I am on A.php and try to view b.php (non-existent page) .. .htaccess redirects me to my_404.php on which I see `HTTP_REFERER` as A.php .. but what I am looking for is that "somebody tried to view B.php". How do I do that?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Please see: I dont want to check in log files. I am asking about something on page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a remote ErrorDocument URL like `http://mysite.com/my_404.php`, Apache will send a redirect to that URL to the client, that's why you can't get the URL that causes the 404 from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` like Matt Bridges suggested.
You might want to try using a local ErrorDocument (no scheme and servername), like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my_404.php
```

I suspect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will then return the originally requested URL.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely already being done in your Apache log file. You could just parse the data rather than recording it twice.

Stackoverflow Archives:

- [How can I parse Apache's error log in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159393/how-can-i-parse-apaches-error-log-in-php)

Additional Relevant Content:

- [Apache Log Parser Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2596.html) via PHPClasses.org

Comment: I dont want to check log files. I just want to check it when I am on 404 page. I am not trying to record the data twice.

Answer (score 2):

The variable you are looking for is called $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].  It holds the original request that was made to your server by the client.

You can see a list of the other "$_SERVER" variables [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Edit:

After a bit of google searching, your problem is that your error page is specified with the http:// qualifier. Change your htaccess so that the ErrorDocument is specified as a local file, e.g.:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /www/my_404.php
```

After you do that, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] should hold the correct value.

Comment: @Matt .. yes it works greate now. Thank you for helping me out. @steef also answered the same. so which I should mark as answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `$_SERVER` array in `my_404.php`

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

I guess you'll find what you need. :-)

Comment: Done it. Nothing helpfule. I mean, mentioning, b.php.

Comment: What if you try "ErrorDocument 404 /my_404.php" (without the host)?