# Formatting PHP Echo

Tags: php, html, css

I want to have a small text box with a scroll bar that will hold frequent outputs from PHP based on server-side activity. How do I set up formatting like this?

Comment: By frequent outputs do you mean a lot of output, like debugging output?

Comment: It is debugging output, but its not a huge amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either use a `<pre>` or multiple `<div>`s (one per line) instead of an input element. That way, you don't have to deal with making the input element read-only. If you use `<div>`s, then you can also add classes to each line to style messages of different severity differently (for example, errors are red, warnings are orange etc.)

Comment: And then add overflow: auto CSS if you really need those scroll bars ;)

Answer (score 2):

The box:

```
<iframe style="overflow:auto; width:100px" src="status.php"/>
```

And in status.php you parse a log file, as explained here

[How can I parse Apache's error log in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159393/how-can-i-parse-apaches-error-log-in-php)

And you log interesting events/errors/warnings/debug in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply echo out a text box or input box and make the value a variable which you can set however you like:

### Textbox

```
echo '<textarea>' . $value . '</textarea>';
```

### Input

```
echo '<input type="text" value="' . $value . '" />';
```

You can make these read only, and adjust the other HTML attributes as you like. Hope this helps.

Comment: The textbox should be textarea and the value goes in between the opening and closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you really want is something like Gmail or Facebook chat (sort of **push messages into the browser**).

If that's what you're looking for go after the keyword '**Comet**' otherwise you can just use an AJAX repeater to query the page every 'x' seconds and fetch new messages.